# Submitting two forms separately in one page with separate thankyou message

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've a page which have two different forms:

Form 1:

```
<form id="info-form" method="POST" action="">
    <label for="name">What is your Name? </label> 
    <input required type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your full name here." />

    <label for="email">What is your email ID? </label>
    <input required type="email" name="email" placeholder="your.name@email.com" />

    <label for="mobile-number">What is your 10-Digit Mobile Number? </label>
    <input required type="text" name="mobile-number" maxlength="10" placeholder="Enter num." />

    <label for="posting-place">What is your current place of residence? </label>
    <input type="text" name="place" placeholder="Enter your current residing place here." />

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">
        Submit
    </button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">
        Reset
    </button>
</form>
```

Form 2:

```
<form id="contact-form" method="POST" action="">
    <label for="name">What is your Name? </label> 
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your full name here." />

    <label for="email">What is your email ID? </label>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="your email" />

    <label for="message"> Your Message: </label>
    <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Type in your message here"></textarea>

    <button id="submit_button" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">
        Send
    </button>
    <button id="reset_button" type="reset" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">
        Reset
    </button>
</form>
```

I then have these below thank you messages after the closing `form` tag of both the above two forms

Thank you message after submitting Form 1:

```
<div style="display:none;" id="thankyou_form">
    <p><em>Thank You</em> for submitting!</p>
</div>
```

Thank you message after submitting Form 2:

```
<div style="display:none;" id="thankyou_contact">
    <p><em>Thank You</em> for contacting! We will get back to you soon!</p>
</div>
```

I then have **two** script for displaying the thank you message on the same page after the form is submitted.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () 
    {
        $('form').submit(function (e) 
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax(
            {                   
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (response) 
                {
                    console.log(response);
                    if(response.result == 'success') 
                    {
                        // this is for the second form. For the 1st form ID is changed to thankyou_form
                        document.getElementById("thankyou_contact").style.display = "inline";
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        // this is for the second form. For the 1st form ID is changed to thankyou_form
                        document.getElementById("thankyou_contact").style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

But when I **submit the second form** the thankyou message is **also displayed is the first form**. Also, the form is **submitted twice**.

Can you please inform me how to identify both the javascript separately? Or, Can I combine both the script into one but both submit buttons working independently of each other?

It would be very much helpful and also enlightening for me if you can point out my mistake.

P.S. I'm a beginner.

Edit1: The javascript code was modified (but currently non-working) as per suggestion from David. The new code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () 
            {
                $('form').submit(function (e) 
                {
                    if(e.target === 'form#info-form')
                    {                   
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: this.action,
                            type: this.method,
                            data: $(this).serialize(),
                            success: function (response) 
                            {
                                console.log(response);
                                if(response.result == 'success') 
                                {
                                    document.getElementById("thankyou_info").style.display = "inline";
                                } 
                                else 
                                {
                                    document.getElementById("thankyou_info").style.display = "none";
                                    document.getElementById("sorry_info").style.display = "inline";
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    if(e.target === 'form#contact-form')
                    {                   
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: this.action,
                            type: this.method,
                            data: $(this).serialize(),
                            success: function (response) 
                            {
                                console.log(response);
                                if(response.result == 'success') 
                                {
                                    document.getElementById("thankyou_contact").style.display = "inline";
                                } 
                                else 
                                {
                                    document.getElementById("thankyou_contact").style.display = "none";
                                    document.getElementById("sorry_contact").style.display = "inline";
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Please submit the form using their IDs instead of directly submitting using form element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `event.target` to determine which form is getting submitted, You need to refine your code as,

```
   if(response.result == 'success') 
   {
       // Determine if the submission came from "Info Form" or "Contact Form"
        if(e.target === 'form#info-form')
        {
           document.getElementById("thankyou_form").style.display = "inline";
        }
        else 
        {
           document.getElementById("thankyou_contact").style.display = "inline";
        }
   } 
   else 
   {
       // this is for the second form. For the 1st form ID is changed to thankyou_form
     document.getElementById("thankyou_form").style.display = "none";  
     document.getElementById("thankyou_contact").style.display = "none";
   }
```

Comment: Hello @David. Thank you for your suggestion. However the code does not seems to be executing as on form submission I'm getting the URL response code in a new page (and not the thank you message in the same page). The code that I modified is pasted in the above question as "Edit1".

Comment: Can you clarify, whether the submission is happening twice as earlier (or) only one time after this change?

Comment: Now my submission is happening once only. This, I think, is because I now have one function call ($(function ()) instead of the earlier 2. However I don't think the function is executing at all because now I'm getting the same response which I used to get without any Javascript.

Comment: @ABor, So basically you want to have the "Thank you" message in the same page instead of getting it in the new url right?

Comment: Right. With my previous script I was able to achieve the same, but the script used to run for both the forms in the page. As a result, even though I submit only one form, I used to get a thank you message below both forms + data submission for both the forms. But with this modified script even though I'm getting only one form submission (which was the case without the script) I'm being redirected to a page showing the actual URL response.

Comment: Yup.. I have updated the code, Instead of making two calls, we can check the `target` form in the 'success` block. Check my updated code.

Comment: Thanks @David. That worked. I would do some more extensive testing with both the forms. But it seems that now the logic is correct. Thanks again.